# VueJs - Best practice for loop between two numbers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

what is the best practice to set value for a select option using loop between A, B with `v-for`?

for example. between 1900-2010

```
   <option v-for="i in (1900 to 2010)" :value="i"> {{ i }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li v-for="i in (2010 - 1900 + 1)" :value="i + 1900"> {{ i + 1900 }} </li>
```

You can change 2010 and 1900 to your max in min number.

```
 <li v-for="i in (max - min + 1)" :value="i + min"> {{ i + min }} </li>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mmbq7xpx/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to generate such objects in a controller to don't store business logic in a template.

I used lodash [_.range](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#range) to generate the range array.

```js
const min = 1900;
const max = 2010;
    
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    years: _.range(min, max + 1)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select>
    <option v-for="i in years" :value="i"> {{ i }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```